# Cannot access properties inside objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

In my react app i'm mapping an array like below

```
{(newdata !== null) ? newdata && newdata.map((item,key) => {
       console.log("item ",item);
         return (
            <div>{item.image_location}</div>
         )
    }
 ):null
}
```

And my console log looks like this

[image]

But cannot object the `image_location` attribute or any other attributes in the item object. i tried `item.image_location` but it returns a `undefined`. How to access the attributes inside my `item` object

I tried accessing like this

```
const newkey = parseInt(key)+1; console.log("item ",item.$['place_'+newkey]);
```

Still i get a undefined error

LATEST CODE

```
{(newdata !== null) ? newdata && newdata.map((item, key) => {
                        var newkey = parseInt(key) + 1;
                        console.log("item ", item['place_' + newkey]);
                        return (

                            <Row noGutters className="container_one polaroid unchange_div" key={key}>

                                <Col xs={4} className="attraction_container">
                                    <img src={item.image_location} alt="img"
                                         className="attraction_img"/>
                                </Col>

                            </Row>
                        )
                    }) : (countrydata === null && loading === false) ?
                        <div className="horiz_center"><span className="nodata_lbl">No data</span>
                        </div> : null
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the log, you can clearly see that, the `image_location` attribute is wrapped inside `place_1` attribute. So, you have to access it like `item.place_1.image_location`

**Update**

```
{(newdata !== null) ? newdata && Object.keys(newdata).sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.split('_')[1]) - parseInt(b.split('_')[1])).forEach((key) => {
    console.log("item ", newdata[key]);
    return (
      <Row noGutters className="container_one polaroid unchange_div" key={key}>
        <Col xs={4} className="attraction_container">
          <img src={newdata[key].image_location} alt="img" className="attraction_img"/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }) : (countrydata === null && loading === false) ? 
      <div className="horiz_center"><span className="nodata_lbl">No data</span>
    </div> : null
}
```

Comment: i tried const newkey = parseInt(key)+1;
                                console.log("item ",item.$['place_'+newkey]);

Still i get a undefined error

Comment: yh that worked but weirdly i just get the result of the first object. Others are getting undefined. I checked if my newkey is looped correctly. And it does. Can't figure out the reason

Comment: The keys are iterated in alphabetical order, so you are trying to access place_2 when the correct value is place_10.  Are you able to restructure your data model so it's just an array of objects without the place_* step in between?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD could you edit your question adding your latest code at the bottom for better understanding?

Comment: Please check the Update in my answer @CraZyDroiD